# Plotting large gts objects in dygraphs

Tags: r, dygraphs

I am new to R programming. I've generated a hierarchical time series using the hts package.I need to plot time series in each hierarchy separately using dygraphs.

```
    library(hts)
    abc <- ts(5 + matrix(sort(rnorm(1000)), ncol = 10, nrow = 100))
    colnames(abc) <- c("A10A", "A10B", "A10C", "A20A", "A20B",
               "B30A", "B30B", "B30C", "B40A", "B40B")
     y <- hts(abc, characters = c(1, 2, 1))

     fcasts1 <- forecast(y, method = "bu" ,h=4, fmethod = "arima", 
                     parallel = TRUE)

     dygraph(fcasts1,y)
```

I keep getting this error message ,

```
  Error in UseMethod("as.xts") : 
  no applicable method for 'as.xts' applied to an object of class "c('gts', 'hts')"
```

Is there a solution for this issue ?Maybe if someone could tell me how to put the variables right in dygraph.

Comment: You should provide a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input data so we can run the code and see what's going on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to directly plot hts objects using dygraph. What you need to do is convert the hts$bts object into a matrix and then convert into a normal time series using ts() function.

Here is an example I've worked out.

```
library(hts)
abc <- ts(5 + matrix(sort(rnorm(1000)), ncol = 10, nrow = 100))
colnames(abc) <- c("A10A", "A10B", "A10C", "A20A", "A20B",
                   "B30A", "B30B", "B30C", "B40A", "B40B")
y <- hts(abc, characters = c(1, 2, 1))

fcasts1 <- forecast.gts(y, method = "bu" ,h=4, fmethod = "arima", 
                         parallel = TRUE)
ts1 <- as.matrix(fcasts1$bts)
ts1 <- ts(ts1,start = c(2016,3), frequency = 12)
dygraph(ts1[,"A10A"],main='Sample dygraph ',ylab = 'Demand')
```

Comment: Thanks Thisara , It was very helpful